# SAS: Macro not resolved within macro environment

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a macro that will execute other SAS scripts based on a check of the week.

```
data _null_;

    week_num = week(); /*Current week is 31*/
    call symput('week_num',week_num);

run;

%macro testmacro(week_num);

    %if &week_num. = 31 %then %do;
        %put This works;
    %end;

%mend testmacro;

%testmacro(%week_num.);
```

I have used week 31 as an example, since this is the week of posting this question. I keep getting the message: WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro WEEK_NUM not resolved. I do not understand what I am missing to get the macro to be called correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a macro **variable** named WEEK_NUM, but you are trying to execute a macro named WEEK_NUM instead of referencing the macro variable you created.

Use & to reference a macro variable and % to execute a macro.  So in this line TESTMACRO is an actual macro and WEEK_NUM is a macro variable (also called a symbol).

```
%testmacro(&week_num.);
```